# Python - ModuleNotFoundError while installing a new package

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip, flask-login

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Flask(1.1.2) in which I have created my custom packages, it's working correctly, but now I need to install a new pip package called `flask-login`, so when I run the command as `pip install flask-login` it gives `ModuleNotFoundError` for one of my custom modules.

Here's my directory structure for this Flask project:

```
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
├── app.py
├── auth.py
├── books.sqlite
├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── connection.py
│   └── db.py
├── frontend
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
```

When I run the command `pip install flask-login` here's the error I got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/abdul/PycharmProjects/BookLi/venv/bin/pip", line 5, in
>
> from pip._internal.cli.main import main   File "/Users/abdul/PycharmProjects/BookLi/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py",
> line 10, in 
> from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete   File "/Users/abdul/PycharmProjects/BookLi/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py",
> line 9, in 
> from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser   File
> "/Users/abdul/PycharmProjects/BookLi/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py",
> line 7, in 
> from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions   File "/Users/abdul/PycharmProjects/BookLi/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py",
> line 25, in 
> from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix   File
> "/Users/abdul/PycharmProjects/BookLi/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py",
> line 11, in 
> import frontend ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend'

what's can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with `Flask-Login`, as the installation works like a charm. I just tested it.

Also, `frontend` is not a dependency of `Flask-Login`.

Are you really sure you typed in the shown command?

It looks like you are using `PyCharm`? Maybe it does some magic in the background.

I would recommend to delete the current environment and recreate it.